# Take picture, save into Gallery and pick the Uri in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-gallery

I'm trying to launch the camera to take a picture, then save it into gallery and recover the Uri, to show it into image view.

With this, later on I will send it to FirebaseStorage.

(I simplified names of variables and methods to do ir more readable)

At this moment I got the click action that checks the permissions needed.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            val permissions = arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )

            Permissions.check(context!!, permissions, null, null, object : PermissionHandler() {
                override fun onGranted() {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent()
                }
            })
        }


private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context!!.packageManager)?.also {
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.d("PictureIntent", "Error trying to get file")
                    null
                }
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        context!!,
                        "com.elias.myapplication.fileprovider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    activity!!.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Following the documentation of google, in Manifest I added the declaration of FileProvider like this:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

And here is where all the problems come...

In the xml file `file_paths` if I put the path like example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.elias.myapplication/files/Pictures/" />
</paths>
```

I get this error:

```
Process: com.elias.myapplication, PID: 24093
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.elias.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainFragment.kt:76)
        at com.elias.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment.access$dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainFragment.kt:28)
        at com.elias.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment$onViewCreated$1$1.onGranted(MainFragment.kt:59)
        at com.nabinbhandari.android.permissions.Permissions.check(Permissions.java:105)
        at com.el.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment$onViewCreated$1.onClick(MainFragment.kt:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Reading more question on SO, i found a "solution". Modify the xml file with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
  <external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
  <cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="." />
  <external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="." />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

With this solution doesn't crash, BUT, in the `onActivityResult`, the intent arrives `null`

And here is where I'm lost.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Go through [this](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider)

Comment: Thanks for the link @HemantParmar ! good explanation

Answer (score 0):

> I get this error:

`path` is relative to the base location defined in the element name. Use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

> BUT, in the onActivityResult, the intent arrives null

It's supposed to be `null`. You know where the image is supposed to be: in the location identified by `photoFile`. Look for it there. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Camera/FileProvider) for an example of using `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.